# Как прочитать NDEF сообщение? (M24SR04-Y)

Tags: c++, c

У меня есть микросхема M24SR04-Y, на которую я записал информацию с помощью NFC.
Мне нужно прочитать эту информацию, используя i2c.
Я прочитал техническое описание и понял схему связи с микросхемой.
Но я новичок и без примера очень трудно понять как это делать на практике.

Скажите пожалуйста как и в какой форме отправлять команды? Если вы покажете пример общения с чипом - будет здорово!

Comment: Микросхема M24SR04-Y разве широко извесна? Извесны пики, атмелы, ардуино накрайняк.

Comment: Какими аппаратными средствами вы располагаете? Какой у вас контроллер? Или проблема в понимании протокола?

Comment: M24SR04-Y подключена к плате на PowerPC 440EP, на ней стоит Linux. Проблема в понимании протокола. То есть не в том, что не могу связаться с платой, а в том, что не знаю как( 
Я пытался прочитать ее как обычную EEPROM, но не получилось. Выдавал абракадабру. Потом я прочитал, что к ней нельзя получить доступ таким способом и теперь не знаю как быть дальше.

Answer (score 1):

> как и в какой форме отправлять команды?

Это должно быть описано в даташите на эту микросхему. Файл даташита можно найти, к примеру, тут:

https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1044737/STMicroelectronics/M24SR04-Y/1